# MongoDB queries in Kibana

Tags: json, mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana

I want to know how to write a MongoDB query (Json) in Kibana's Query textbox. FYI : I'm using Kibana 3. I've tried to copy the mongodb's json like query into the query box and run it, but nothing was happened.

If anyone has an experience about that, I'll be thankfull for the help.:)

Comment: Kibana queries Elasticsearch, not Mongo.

Comment: I see. If I have a MongoDB data, how can I query it in Kibana?

Comment: You will need to index it in Elasticsearch somehow. The specifics are up to your particular implementation.

Comment: Can You give me a link about that? thanks :)

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try [logstash-input-mongodb](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb)

Basically, I think you need to index mongodb data with logstash and output to elasticsearch, before you can search/visualize it with kibana.

**Mongodb=>logstash=>elasticsearch=>kibana**

I have recently implemented visualizing some kind of audit log from mongodb with kibana under the help of this logstash plugin.